# Move Recent Order List to Top Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3

In Magento V2.3.3 Recent orders shown at the bottom of the Account section. I tried to move recent orders to the top by using the below code, it's not working for me.

[image]

```
<move element="customer_account_dashboard_top" destination="customer_account_navigation" before="-"/>
```

Guide me on how to move the recent orders to the top. And also guide me on how to rearrange the MyAccount left sidebar links (My Account, My Orders, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to update below line in your `customer_account_index.xml`

```
<move element="customer_account_dashboard_top" destination="content" before="-" />
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Any suggestions on how to rearrange MyAccount Dashboard links.

Comment: You can accept my answer if that helps :) and for another question you can check this [link](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-add-delete-re-order-custom-links.html)

Comment: Hi @KishanSavaliya https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/304647/magento-2-hide-shipping-methods-based-on-product-attribute