# Magento 2 hide shipping methods based on product attribute & shipping address out of USA

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, hide

I Would like to hide shipping methods and display a custom message on the checkout page & cart page based on product attribute flag & if the shipping address is outside of the USA.

I used the below plugin but it triggers only logged-in users unable to verify with guest users.

Could you please advise what exact plugin or method want to use?

Note: It should work guest users & registered customers

app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
        <plugin name="disableshippingmethod" type="Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Plugin\ShippingMethodManagementPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/Plugin/ShippingMethodManagementPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Plugin;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Exception;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;
class ShippingMethodManagementPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var QuoteFactory
     */
    protected $quoteFactory;


    /**
     * ShippingMethodManagementPlugin constructor.
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
     * @param QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    )
    {
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this ->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param $cartId
     * @param $addressId
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function afterEstimateByAddressId(\Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement $subject, $result, $cartId, $addressId)
    {
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($cartId);
        $items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
        $productAttributeValues = array();
        $shippWithinUsaFlag = ['1'];
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $productAttributeValues[$item->getSku()] = $item->getProduct()->getData('ship_only_within_usa');
        }

        //Fetch current Country Id US/IN based on shipping address id
        $countryIdFlag = $this->getCustomerAddress($addressId);
        //Unset shipping methods based on product attribute & shipping address
        $restrictionFlag = (count(array_intersect($productAttributeValues, $shippWithinUsaFlag))) ? '1' : '0';
        if($countryIdFlag !== "US" && $restrictionFlag === '1'){
            /** @var TYPE_NAME $result */
            foreach ($result as $key => $shippingMethod) {
                 unset($result[$key]);
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param $addressId
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getCustomerAddress($addressId)
    {
        $countryId = null;
        try {
            $addressRepository = $this->addressRepository->getById($addressId);
            $countryId=$addressRepository->getCountryId();
            return $countryId;
        }  catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->logger->error("Something went wrong with customer address".$exception->getMessage());
        }
        return $countryId;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can try this extension https://marketplace.magento.com/ambab-module-skipshipping.html, add write your logic in Helper/Data.php : isEnabled() method

Answer (score 1):

After did some research on this task I have found a solution for this. Here I am posting the solution based on the requirement it may help others if the will get the same kind of task as per the requirement.

> 1. app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/etc/catalog_attributes.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
    <group name="quote_item">
        <attribute name="ship_only_within_usa"/>
    </group>
</config>
```

> 2. app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
       <preference for="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping" type="Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Model\Shipping" />
 </config>
```

> 3. app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/Model/Shipping.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Model;

class Shipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping {

    /**
     * @param string $carrierCode
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     * @return $this|\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping
     */
    public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {
        /* @var $carrier \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier */
        $carrier = $this->_carrierFactory->createIfActive($carrierCode, $request->getStoreId());
        if (!$carrier) {
            return $this;
        }
        /**-------- Custom logic starts here --------**/

        $restrictionFlag=0;
        $productAttributeValues = array();
        $shippWithInUsaFlag = ['1'];
        $request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $productAttributeValues[$item->getSku()]=$item->getProduct()->getData('ship_only_within_usa');
        }
        $restrictionFlag = (count(array_intersect($productAttributeValues, $shippWithInUsaFlag))) ? 'restrict' : 'notrestrict';
        $countryCode=$request->getDestCountryId();
        if('restrict' === $restrictionFlag && "US" !== $countryCode) {
            return $this;
        }

         /**-------- Custom logic ends here --------**/

        $carrier->setActiveFlag($this->_availabilityConfigField);
        $result = $carrier->checkAvailableShipCountries($request);
        if (false !== $result && !$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
            $result = $carrier->processAdditionalValidation($request);
        }
        /*
         * Result will be false if the admin set not to show the shipping module
         * if the delivery country is not within specific countries
         */
        if (false !== $result) {
            if (!$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
                if ($carrier->getConfigData('shipment_requesttype')) {
                    $packages = $this->composePackagesForCarrier($carrier, $request);
                    if (!empty($packages)) {
                        $sumResults = [];
                        foreach ($packages as $weight => $packageCount) {
                            $request->setPackageWeight($weight);
                            $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                            if (!$result) {
                                return $this;
                            } else {
                                $result->updateRatePrice($packageCount);
                            }
                            $sumResults[] = $result;
                        }
                        if (!empty($sumResults) && count($sumResults) > 1) {
                            $result = [];
                            foreach ($sumResults as $res) {
                                if (empty($result)) {
                                    $result = $res;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                foreach ($res->getAllRates() as $method) {
                                    foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $resultMethod) {
                                        if ($method->getMethod() == $resultMethod->getMethod()) {
                                            $resultMethod->setPrice($method->getPrice() + $resultMethod->getPrice());
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                }
                if (!$result) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
            if ($carrier->getConfigData('showmethod') == 0 && $result->getError()) {
                return $this;
            }
            // sort rates by price
            if (method_exists($result, 'sortRatesByPrice') && is_callable([$result, 'sortRatesByPrice'])) {
                $result->sortRatesByPrice();
            }
            $this->getResult()->append($result);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to do using plugin then give a try below.

**Change required in**: Country name and product attribute name and attribute getter :)

**File: app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
        <plugin name="shiprules_collect_valid_methods"
                type="Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Plugin\CollectValidMethods"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

**File: app/code/Vendor/ShippingRestriction/Plugin/CollectValidMethods.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ShippingRestriction\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\ProductFactory as ProductResourceModel;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory as RateErrorFactory;

class CollectValidMethods
{
    private $request = false;

    public function __construct(
        ProductResourceModel $productResource,
        RateErrorFactory     $rateErrorFactory
    )
    {
        $this->productResource = $productResource;
        $this->rateErrorFactory = $rateErrorFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
     */
    public function beforeCollectRates(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping               $subject,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping|void
     */
    public function afterCollectRates(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
                                         $result)
    {
        /*$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/checkoutAttrRestrictions.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);*/

        $countryCode = $this->request->getDestCountryId();
        //This can be easily replace with some config helper
        $countryCodeToCheck = 'US';
        $attrName = 'ship_only_within_usa';

        if ($countryCodeToCheck !== $countryCode) {
            return $subject;
        }
        //$logger->info($countryCode);
        $attributeRestrict = false;
        $restrictionFlag = 0;
        $productAttributeValues = array();
        $shippWithInUsaFlag = ['1'];
        $allItems = $this->request->getAllItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $_product = $item->getProduct();
            //In case straightforward attribute
            //$attrVal = $_product->getResource()->getData($attrName);
            //In case attribute has frontend value
            $attrVal = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attrName)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

            if (!empty($attrVal) && in_array($attrVal,$shippWithInUsaFlag)) {
                $attributeRestrict = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        $result = $subject->getResult();
        if (!($rates = $result->getAllRates())) {
            return $subject;
        }

        //$logger->info($attributeRestrict);
        if(!$attributeRestrict){
            return $subject;
        }
        $result->reset();
        $errorMsg = 'Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time';
        foreach ($rates as $rate) {
            $restrict = false;
            if ($countryCode == $countryCodeToCheck ) {
                $restrict = true;
            }
            $error = $this->rateErrorFactory->create();
            $error->setCarrier($rate->getCarrier());
            $error->setCarrierTitle($rate->getCarrierTitle());
            $error->setErrorMessage($errorMsg);
            $result->append($error);

            if (!$restrict) {
                $result->append($rate);
            }
        }
        return $subject;
    }
}
```